# Sequential composing AsyncTasks in Android with Kotlin

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kotlin

I'm pretty new to Kotlin and I want to compose AsyncTask executions similarly like I would do in Scala to make them run sequentialy(to avoid race condition):

```
def f(): Future[Unit]
def g(): Future[Unit]
f.map(_ -> g)
```

or

```
for {
  _ <- f
  _ <- g
} yield ()
```

To do this I would want to extend somehow my helper:

```
fun doAsync(handler: () -> Unit): AsyncTask<Void, Void, Unit> =
  object : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Unit>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?) {
      try {
        handler()
      }
      catch (t: Throwable) { 
        Log.e("AsyncTask", "fail", t)
      }
    }
  }.execute()
```

I know there is something like `onPostExecute` but I don't know how to change my helper to use it.

Comment: Have just one `AsyncTask`, rather than two. Or, consider using other threading solutions (RxJava, Kotlin coroutines, etc.) instead of the old `AsyncTask` approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async tasks, after **Honey Comb** are run sequentially.
Quoting from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask)

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with Build.VERSION_CODES.DONUT, this was
>   changed to a pool of threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in
>   parallel. Starting with Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB, tasks are
>   executed on a single thread to avoid common application errors caused
>   by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

And, async task is designed for small operations, if you have a long running one, better use other Api s.

Also, you can always specify an executor, by calling executeOnExecutor()